# Enumerating all instantiations of template

Tags: c++, templates, explicit-instantiation

I am reading on type erasure:

[Andrzej's C++ blog Type erasure — Part I](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/11/18/type-erasure-part-i/)

Where I come across the following text:

> unless you can enumerate all instantiations of your template in
>   advance, you have to include the body of each function template in the
>   header file, you cannot separate the declaration from the
>   implementation

Is enumerating all instantiations of the template the same as explicit instantiation pointed out in answer to the following question?

[Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

> Another solution is to keep the implementation separated, and
>   explicitly instantiate all the template instances you'll need:

```
// Foo.h

// no implementation
template <typename T> struct Foo { ... };

//----------------------------------------    
// Foo.cpp

// implementation of Foo's methods

// explicit instantiations
template class Foo<int>;
template class Foo<float>;
// You will only be able to use Foo with int or float
```

Comment: @L.F. edited the original question

Comment: OK.  Yeah, the blogger is apparently referring to explicit instantiation.  You have to know all specializations to be used in advance in order to use explicit instantiation to separate implementation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When would you use template explicit instantiation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068993/when-would-you-use-template-explicit-instantiation)

Comment: Enumerating all instantiations of a template is something the developer does to create a list of those instantiations.   Having that list is necessary to be able to explicitly instantiate the template.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly yes.

What it boils down to is "can you know everywhere this is used?". The authors of `std::vector<T>` *can't* know all the types `T` will be substituted for.

That's the "enumerate all instantiations" step, which is followed by "write down all the explicit instantiations".